# Highland consume and toArray method together

Tags: javascript, node.js, highland.js

Hi people and happy holidays!

I'm trying to consume a stream of csv rows with highland. To do some special processing and avoid passing down the headers to the stream, I'm calling `.consume()` and then I wanted the outcome in an array. The problem is that the callback of `.toArray()` is never called. I'm just curious about this as I already changed my solution to `.map().toArray()` but I still think `.consume()` would be a more elegant solution. ;) This is the piece of code that reads from a csv file and processes the rows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('highland');

const dataStream = fs.createReadStream('file.csv', 'utf8');

_(dataStream)
  .split()
  .consume((err, row, push, next) => {
    console.log('consuming a row', row); // <-- this shows data

    if (err) {
      push(err);
      return next();
    }

    // This condition is needed as .consume() passes an extra {} at the end of the stream <-- donno what this happens!!
    if (typeof row !== 'string') {
      return next();
    }

    const cells = row.split(',');

    if (cells[0] === 'CODE') { // <-- header row
      const { columnNames, columnIndexes } = processHeader(cells)); // <-- not relevant, works okay
      return next();
    }

    console.log('processin content here', processRow(cells)); // <-- not relevant, works okay
    push(null, processRow(cells));
    return next();
  })
  .toArray(rows => console.log('ROWS: ', rows)); // <-- I don't get anything here
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My answer might not be entirely right, as I did look up the docs of [consume](http://highlandjs.org/#consume) again. `consume` seems to return a new stream and you may have to close it so that toArray can actually be called. Also keep in mind that the example just calls push and next and does not do `return next()`. That being said, I would prefer the `map.toArray` if the resulting array is small. Keep in mind that toArray will keep the entire data in memory, which might be something you want to avoid by doing a stream in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @k0pernikus, I'll wrap the login inside `.consume()` with `if () else ()` to avoid the `return next()` and check. And yes, I think I probably end up doing anything I need inside the `.map()` and close the stream with done(). Processing a row at a time will definitely be less memory consuming. :)

Comment: More info for people interested:
- by adding `if() { next () } else () { next() }` to avoid `return next()` does nothing different.
- `.consume()` is correctly returning a new stream as I can process it chaining a `.map()` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Both `consume` and `toArray` consume a stream. You can only consume a stream once. If you try to consume it multiple times the "stream" will be empty.